# password_digest error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, passwords, omniauth

i use omniauth-identity for authentication on my project. i lso use mongodb for database.my identity model is like below:

```
class Identity
  include Mongoid::Document
  include OmniAuth::Identity::Models::Mongoid

  field :name, type: String
  field :email, type: String
  field :password_digest, type: String

  validates_presence_of :name
  validates_uniqueness_of :email
  validates_format_of :email, :with => /^[-a-z0-9_+\.]+\@([-a-z0-9]+\.)+[a-z0-9]{2,4}$/i
end
```

my identities controller is like below:

```
class IdentitiesController < ApplicationController

  def new 
   @identity = env['omniauth.identity']
  end

end
```

i run project. i don't fill in texts. it gives me error

```
Password digest can't be blank
Name can't be blank
Email is invalid
```

problem is here that, `Password digest can't be blank` warning. it must not be an error. How can i solve this?